# Registration Form to Gen Hashed Password with PBKDF2PasswordHasher

Tags: python, django, hash, cryptography, pbkdf2

I'm trying to get my `userPass` field to be hashed with **PBKDF2PasswordHasher** upon successful submission and when submitted to check if the `userNm` field, already exists or not.

I have a **modelform**:

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    userPass = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Password')
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['userNm','userPass']

def clean_RegForm(self):
    cleanedUserName = self.cleaned_data.get('userNm')
    if Client.objects.filter(userNm=cleanedUserName).exists():
        errorMsg = u"Error occurred."
        raise ValidationError(errorMsg)
    else:
        return cleanedUserName
```

a **hasher.py** file to define a custom definition for PBKDF2PasswordHasher:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.hashers import PBKDF2PasswordHasher

    class PBKDF2PasswordHasher(PBKDF2PasswordHasher):
        iterations = PBKDF2PasswordHasher.iterations * 100
```

**a view**

```
def Registration(request):
    RegForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if RegForm.is_valid():
            clearUserName = RegForm.cleaned_data['userNm']   
            clearPassNoHash = RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass']
            clearPass = make_password(clearPassNoHash.encode("utf-8"),bcrypt.gensalt(14))

            RegForm.save()
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Newuser/?userNm=' + clearUserName)
            except:
                raise ValidationError(('Invalid request'), code='300')    ## [ TODO ]: add a custom error page here.
    else:
        RegForm = RegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'reuse/register.html', {
            'RegForm': RegForm 
        })
```

**settings.py** has:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'MyApp.hashers.MyPBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',                  
)
```

It currently outputs the userNm on the next page, and saves both `userNm` and `userPass` to database, but the `userPass` is cleartext.

What am I doing wrong here? can someone help?